# Javascript Weird Code

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain what the code below does? what do both the .extend() and . register() do to the require('something')?

```
module.exports = require('something')
    .extend(function() {})
    .register('another thing');
```

Comment: That depends on what `something` does. Those are methods of the `something` module.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: here is the sample code: https://github.com/edenjs/ipay88/blob/master/ipay88/base.js
Ferhad Othman, are you sure this and the merging are the same thing?

Comment: deceze, I don't see those methods (extend and register) in his eden-class.js

here is the code: https://github.com/edenjs/class/blob/master/class.js

Comment: @DNAngel Then they're probably inherited from `classified-magic`

Comment: Bergi, magic is cool, but I hate it when it is in code. =(

Please advise if you guys know what the methods do. I am in JS for about 2 months, so any helps would be awesome. I'll take a look at it as well.

Comment: I found that `classified-magic` github was taken down. https://github.com/cblanquera/magic